# Getting error of Access cors orgin error react.js node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

i am getting this error while doing PUT request to my backend server

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/admin/user/5e7b7ad1be58ad279ceee01c' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

and i have enabled cors also in my backend app.js file this is my cors enable code

```
     const app = express();
     var cors = require('cors');
     app.use(cors());
```

So i am not able to get what is the issue is there as other all API's are working fine but i am getting issue in this API only

My react API calling code

```
                fetch(Config.APIURL+Config.adminUser+ '/' + id, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${setToken}`,
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then((result) => {
                result.json().then((resp) => {
                    if (resp.code === 200 ) {
                        NotificationManager.success('Packages are upgraded')
                        this.props.Services(resp.data.services)
                        // idArray.push(resp.data.services[0].selectedIds)
                    } else {

                    }
                })
            })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("error",err);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check section 'Examples of access control scenarios` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Hey i am aware about what cors is but my issue is not of learning basics of cors i know that issue is that i have enabled all things for cors then also this 2 API's are giving me cors issue and all other API's just works fine

that i am not able to catch so please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: Because this request deals with token authentification, it may have other header requirements like `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2018/09/12/authorization-header-and-cors/